# Showing Runtime Errors in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error

Since JavaScript Alerts Are deprecated and I Do Not wish to use modal boxes. How Can I show Runtime errors which happen in the code behind in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to see errors that are not configuration errors but they are logic errors of your application then you should keep logs.

Comment: FYI, if you simply turn on ASP.NET Health Monitoring, it will log to the event log for you.